# Optimizing battery life via colour schemes

Tags: battery-life, themes, super-amoled

I have been looking for a way to change everything on my phone to black (and pure green), since the screen is the main power consumer.

> "the Green OLEDs provide 10 times more Brightness per watt than Blue OLEDs."

[Source](http://www.displaymate.com/OLED_Galaxy_S123_ShootOut_1.htm)

Could someone make a way to do this? A perfect theme, perhaps combined with a filter.

I went through 4 themes so far, and they all fail majorly in some things (not overlapping).